# jquery scripts not working after changing AngularJS templates

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I'm working on an single-page-app in which we use templates like that:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="content.html"> some HTML </script>
```

I was working on one module separately from main project and now I want to include it. The problem is that I have quite a lot of  jQuery scripts there and when I include my html as a template in a directive jQuery doesn't work. I guess why it is so. Jquery can't see chaning templates in Angular. What can do to make jQuery work? I wanted to use $.live() method but it is not supported anymore. Anyone can help?

Comment: `some HTML` in script tags what is the purpose of it?

Comment: it's html which is included to the document as a template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="content.html"> some HTML </script>
```

to

```
<div id="someid" ng-include="'../content.html'"></div>
```

And you have to include jquery plugin before angular js plugin otherwise it will take jqlite .

Instead of `.live` you can use `.on`